How to change the physical resolution of an Android system?
I am using an Android hardware device without a screen, and I operate it via screen casting. However, the physical resolution is set very low, like 132x132. I tried changing the resolution using adb shell wm size, but after the change, the screen casting goes black. And this method is limited to change to double the physical size, which is still very small.
Is there a way to successfully change the physical resolution of the Android system? Are there any alternative methods to adjust the resolution without causing issues with the display?
